# Android R cannot be resolved to a variable in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

I create an android project in Eclipse. I get an error. I researched this problem but any solutions didn't work. Any help will be appreciated.

> R cannot be resolved to a variable

[image]

Comment: This is a pretty common error in Android dev on eclipse. Please check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error?rq=1 It has many of the most common causes of this errror. Also, without any more info, its impossible to say why that error is happening.

Comment: Have you considered Android Studio?

Comment: clean your project

Answer (score 0):

The main solution here is to fix your XML files. There's something wrong with them and R.java can't be built.